# Trying to install Outlook as a PWA: wrong manifest fiile link on Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, outlook, progressive-web-apps

I'm trying to install Outlook as a PWA (https://outlook.office.com) but the button to install it is not displayed. It is possible on Egde browser, and I was able to install it, but it's annoying for me since my default browser is Chrome.

When I check what is going wrong in the Chrome Console, I can see it tries to download the manifest file from here https://outlook.office.com/mail/manifests/pwa.json?culture=fr

Notice the culture parameter which is added. Going on that link return an invalid XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Error><Code>BlobNotFound</Code><Message>The specified blob does not exist.
RequestId:61dcf34d-901e-003c-1e84-fae306000000
Time:2022-11-17T12:57:14.6332369Z</Message></Error>
```

Removing the parameter, and going here https://outlook.office.com/mail/manifests/pwa.json displays the XML of the manifest properly

I tried to remove all my cookies/history, it did not change anything.

Does anyone also encounter this kind of problem and fixed it?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Non-programming questions go to superuser.com web site.

Answer (score 0):

If you open up outlooks web setting and then go through to all settings set the language to English (United States) and then restart your Web app https://support.google.com/chromebook/thread/175421592?hl=en&msgid=180181854